# multiple columns in R Markdown HTML report written in .R script

Tags: r, r-markdown, multiple-columns

I got to edit a report written in Markdown in `.r` script. The report is generated from `ShinyApp`.
I'd like to be able to put the graph and table in parallel columns, and everything before and after this snippet in one column.
I would like to get an effect similar to the layout in Shiny:

```
fluidRow(...),
fluidRow(
   column(8, graph),
   column(4, table)
)
fluidRow(...)
```

My code:

```
#' ---
#' title: Test
#' output:
#'    html_document:
#'      toc: true
#'      toc_depth: 2
#' ---
#' ##### Oryginal ######
#+include=FALSE
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)

#+ echo=FALSE
library(plotly)

#' # Text before plot and table
#' qwertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm qwertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm qwertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm qwertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm qwertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm

table <- data.frame(
  x = c("Apples","Apples","Apples","Organges", "Bananas"),
  y = c("5","10","3","10","5")
)

#' # Plot and table
#' 

#+ echo=FALSE, results = 'asis'
plot_ly(table, y= ~y, x = ~x, histfunc='sum', type = "histogram") %>% layout(yaxis=list(type='linear'))

#+ echo=FALSE, results = 'asis'
print(knitr::kable(table))

#' # Text after plot and table
#' qwertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm qwertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm qwertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm qwertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm qwertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm
```

I found many solustions in internet but nothing works. For example [LINK](https://enzedonline.com/en/tech-blog/adding-multi-column-formats-to-r-markdown-documents/?fbclid=IwAR0khI_JsDKfvQl1_mFQZs2O6LVi7QUZhT12jJKK0jOEFEqgVR7Z5o_z83c).
I got error: `unexpected ':::'`